# Nestjs cache-manager set

Tags: caching, nestjs

Does the Nestjs cache-manager set command replace or append the given values to the key if the key already exists ?
The documentation is not very clear on this

Comment: there's no "nestjs cache-manager", it's just `cache-manager` stuff. Read their docs then. `npm docs cache-manager`

Comment: yes, I read those and they don't provide the info. In fact they are even more vague than the NestJS one, https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the key already exists, `cache-maanger` replace that key. It does not append a new value.

That's true I've not read any docs that explicitly says `.set` override previous data, but you can take a look to the [package tests](https://github.com/node-cache-manager/node-cache-manager/blob/HEAD/test/caching.test.ts).

I've downloaded repository and I've created a new test like this:

```js
it('should override key', async () => {
  cache = await caching(async (arg?: MemoryConfig) => memoryStore(arg));
  await cache.set(key, value);
  await sleep(20);
  await expect(cache.get(key)).resolves.toEqual(value);
  const newValue = 'newValue'
  await cache.set(key, newValue);
  await sleep(20)
  await expect(cache.get(key)).resolves.toEqual(newValue);
})
```

I've overwritten the key and the result is the new one, is not appended.